# Can't use the type with 'import type'

Tags: typescript

This is a method definition:

```
// aFunc.ts
const aFunc = async (input: string) => {
  return { name: input };
};

export default aFunc;
```

I want to use the type of this func in another file using `import type`:

```
import type aFunc from './aFunc';

type API = {
  getName: aFunc;
};
```

I get `'aFunc' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof aFunc'?` error when I use this.

What am I missing? Is there a tsconfig option to enable this? I'm using TypeScript 4.5.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct [syntax for importing type information](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#type-modifiers-on-import-names) is one of the following:

```ts
// type modifier on import names (for mixing with value imports):
import {type Type} from './module';

// importing exclusively types in the statement:
import type {Type} from './module';
```

---

The way to do this in your example is to create the type you want to export so that you can import it in another module:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/PTAEEMDEFcDsGMB0AXAzgWAFBYKYA8AHAewCdlRkBPAnUAQRgVAF5QAeAFVH2R1gBNUoVMhIBLWAHMAfAAoJBaMgBcoDgEoW00AAUSRALZjUONgG9QscAZyquAX2kBuLFnhFYIiI3iqGceBYIVEomKxstUFkLcNp7dRdsTHxiMlB+HAAzcGgAG3IoAMTXTBBQAyJ+PJwUDCSyjgALWg4AZV1c8EpJfTh+dKIcVFgAcnJG8AA3WgM85DECXNpMsSXUYAqqtYAaYSIKZsseUFyJWmNQdwMbWF5+ZSwysQNU8jMqGnofe1BM-QNQCNEMBCggRsVMB9aHQdABJIJmLCgUCSHDIABy1lsXyKWHsTiAA)

```ts
// aFunc.ts

export type AFunc = <T extends string>(input: T) => Promise<{ name: T }>;

const aFunc: AFunc = async name => ({ name });

// Or, you could write it like this:
// const aFunc = async <T extends string>(input: T) => ({ name: input });
// export type AFunc = typeof aFunc;

export default aFunc;
```

```ts
// module.ts

import {type AFunc} from './aFunc';

type API = {
  getName: AFunc;
};
```

---

Edit:

You *can* import only the type information related to a value by using the `type` import modifier when importing the value... however, this only means that you don't have access to the value (but you can still use its type-related information):

```ts
// lowercase aFunc is the function value which is exported as the default export in your example:
import {type default as aFunc} from './aFunc';

type API = {
  getName: typeof aFunc;
};
```

Comment: Thank you. So how come the author of this blog exports the signature of the function without creating an extra type definition: https://colinhacks.com/essays/painless-typesafety

Comment: @ÉlodiePetit I'm not sure what your question is. Are you asking me to read an entire programming blog post?

Comment: Aah sorry for that. Here's a link that shows what he does in that blog post https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEGcFMCcDceNA9gVwC4wHRvAWAFCQAeADktGqAMZIB24lA5pGgKpTSgC8oAhuAE9aVUAAoAlgBMAXBDTRxtRgEpuAPlABvAqFDQWKaLS2gpAGlC1eAW0iyA5ACFxAGwBGSe6AC+AbgJ+BAQg1C7ikLRowIqSxNjgRATi1mQUoGgCJJAmzGwcPqAAZsjWoPaYmMAc8NCIqBjg8fb++AQZWaAAggAKAJLcWjqguewwsiMcLbohvJKSfHPiaOJ0vC569ZDgoAAWMJAVmAEtQA

Comment: @ÉlodiePetit I updated my answer to explain about importing values for their type information. I think that reading the link at the top of my answer will help you understand about the import type modifier: its purpose is for elision of type information during compilation.

Comment: @ÉlodiePetit Here's another playground to illustrate: https://tsplay.dev/NBjbDN

Comment: @jsecksn Thanks a lot for the answers but I still can't get my head around on how that guy used the type without using the `typeof` keyword. I guess his example is wrong then.

Comment: Yes, that’s a syntax error in the blog post.

Comment: @ÉlodiePetit Accept the answer??